# How to split builded dll's in different-different folders

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, msbuild

My Question is, When i am building any solution all the dll's are copied to bin folder. Can we split this dll's with different-different folder's once build is completed? i.e I am having some third party dlls and some other dlls like DevExpress dll's so i want to separate all of then in thier specified folders.
Please dont suggest for manual copy paste. Developers is pulling code from git hub once it is build then folder structure can be made automatically.
Please suggest if we can do with Post-Build Event.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Yes, of course you can create a post-build which copied dlls around, but you're probably going to have to put in the names of the dlls and their targets folders manually, as msbuild might now know which ones are third-party and which ones aren't..

Comment: Hi, You are right, I am doing manually one by one ie.MOVE /Y "$(TargetDir)FleeTime.AdvancedSearch.pdb" "$(TargetDir)\.NetModules\AppLauncher.lib" 
Is there is any way to do it automatically? I thought NANT is another solution to do so, Please share if you do have any idea...

Comment: Are the ones you call 'third party dlls' all those which are added as reference to the project? I.e. in the project file they are defined like `<Reference Include="FleeTime.AdvancedSearch" />`? Maybe it's better if you update your question and show a short list of files you get know, and how you want them to be split up becasue it's not really clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy files through Copy task after build. For example, (add to the end of your project file):

[image]